# How big (in bits) is a Unix UID?

Tags: linux, unix, uid

I understand that unix user IDs (UIDs) are usually 16 or 32 bit unsigned integers but how can I find out for any given system (in a shell)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to look in `<limits.h>` (or one of the files it includes, e.g., `sys/syslimits.h` on OS X) for the `#define` of `UID_MAX`.

Most recent operating systems (Solaris 2.x, OS X, BSD, Linux, HP-UX 11i, AIX 6) can handle up to two billion (`2^31-2`), so I would assume that and make a workaround for the more obscure systems that don't.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `UID_MAX`. For example, tools from `shadow-utils` use `(uid_t)-1` to find out the max value for UID.

Comment: Most systems use /etc/login.defs which does have UID_MAX set for the highest usable UID value, 60000 on any system I've checked.

Comment: The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/login.defs) for `login.defs` indicates that in that context, `UID_MAX` only controls the highest uid that will automatically be assigned for new users created with `useradd`.

Comment: It's probably 2^32 (4 billion instead of 2). On RHEL _UID 4,294,967,295 (2^32-1) is often reserved for an "invalid value" UID, and 4,294,967,294 (2^32-2) is reserved for the nfsnobody user in some operating systems.  Thus the max non-reserved value is 4,294,967,293 (2^32-3)_

Comment: Link to one of many examples of `(uid_t)-1` in shadow-utils: https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/eaebea55a495a56317ed85e959b3599f73c6bdf2/src/newusers.c#L342-L345

Answer (score 6):

glibc provides definitions for all those system types.

You can check `/usr/include/bits/typesizes.h`:

```
% grep UID_T /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h
#define __UID_T_TYPE            __U32_TYPE
```

Next you look into `/usr/include/bits/types.h`:

```
% grep '#define __U32_TYPE' /usr/include/bits/types.h
#define __U32_TYPE              unsigned int
```

This lets you find out the C type. Since you need the size in bytes, your best option is parsing the typedef name according to the specification in `types.h`:

```
We define __S<SIZE>_TYPE and __U<SIZE>_TYPE for the signed and unsigned
variants of each of the following integer types on this machine.

 16      -- "natural" 16-bit type (always short)
 32      -- "natural" 32-bit type (always int)
 64      -- "natural" 64-bit type (long or long long)
 LONG32      -- 32-bit type, traditionally long
 QUAD        -- 64-bit type, always long long
 WORD        -- natural type of __WORDSIZE bits (int or long)
 LONGWORD    -- type of __WORDSIZE bits, traditionally long
```

So, here is a one-liner:

```
% grep '#define __UID_T_TYPE' /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h | cut -f 3 | sed -r 's/__([US])([^_]*)_.*/\1 \2/'
U 32
```

Here `U` means `unsigned` (this can also be `S` for `signed`) and `32` is the size (look it up in the list above; I think, most of the time you can assume that that's already size in bytes, but if you want your script to be fully portable it might be better to do `case` switch on this value).

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 12.04) and other Debian based systems the header file is: `/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)/bits/typesizes.h` or alternatively: `/usr/include/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/bits/typesizes.h`

Comment: Having those glibc files would probably mean that there is a compiler available. So one could _#include <sys/types.h>_ to have access to _uid_t_ and print the result ( _printf("uid_t: %d bytes (%d bits)\n", sizeof(uid_t), sizeof(uid_t) * 8);_ )

Answer (score 4):

In [this link](http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1264128628953+28353475&threadId=1043349) the question is asked and a responder uses a trial & error method to determine the system in question uses a signed long int, leaving 31 bits to store the value, with a max of 2,147,483,647.

```
# groupadd -g 42949672950 testgrp
# more /etc/group
testgrp:*:2147483647:
```

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting question. I'd be surprised if there was a standard, portable method to determine this.

I don't have a Linux box handy, but the `id` command on FreeBSD 8.0 wraps back to zero:

```
# id 4294967296
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),5(operator)
```

I'm sure this is undefined behavior, but I'd wager that most versions of `id` would either wrap to zero with `65'536` (if 16-bit UID) and `4'294'967'296` or error out if you went beyond the system limit.