# What is the minimum and maximum value for --limit option in iptables?

Tags: iptables, firewall, rate-limiting

I have below iptable rule

`iptables -A PRIO_IN -p tcp -s 203.0.113.0 --sport 5432 -d 203.0.113.0 --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT -m limit --limit 100000/sec`

When i run this rule, i get error as `Rate too fast 100000/sec`.

So I want to what is the minimum and maximum value we can pass to `--limit` option with per sec, per min and per hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The max value is 10000

---

Looking at the source code, in [`xt_limit.h`](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/include/linux/netfilter/xt_limit.h) the constant `XT_LIMIT_SCALE` is defined as:

```c
#define XT_LIMIT_SCALE 10000
```

with the comment:

> /* 1/10,000 sec period => max of 10,000/sec.  Min rate is then 429490
> seconds, or one every 59 hours. */

The constant is then used in the `parse_rate()` function in [`libxt_limit.c`](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/extensions/libxt_limit.c#n48), which parses the argument:

```c
*val = XT_LIMIT_SCALE * mult / r;
if (*val == 0)
    /*
     * The rate maps to infinity. (1/day is the minimum they can
     * specify, so we are ok at that end).
     */
    xtables_error(PARAMETER_PROBLEM, "Rate too fast \"%s\"", rate);
```

---

In your case this means:

`mult` is defined as `1` for `seconds`, so the equation ends up as:

```
10000 * 1 / 100000
```

The result is then `0.1` which is then rounded to `0`, raising the error message.

---

So basically the maximum for each time period is the number of seconds in the time period * 10000

| interval | seconds | max value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| second | 1 | 10000 |
| minute | 60 | 600000 |
| hour | 60*60 | 36000000 |
| day | 24*60*60 | 864000000 |

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped me. Also any idea on "--uuid-owner", what can be minimum and maximum value we can pass with this flag ?

Comment: I would expect it to be matching with [usable Unix UIDs](https://serverfault.com/questions/105260/how-big-in-bits-is-a-unix-uid)

Comment: As per this link - https://www.baeldung.com/linux/user-ids-reserved-values#:~:text=For%20Linux%20kernel%20version%202.4,4%2C294%2C967%2C295%2C%20which%20is%2032%20bits.
maximum limit can be 4,294,967,295